# How to select multiple rows that have certain values in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
array([(1596207300,   1), (1596207300,  35), (1596207300,  36),
       (1596207300,  41), (1596207300,  42), (1596207300,  44),
       (1596207300,  49), (1596207300,  50), (1596207300,  51),
       (1596207300,  60), (1596207300,  68), (1596207300,  69),
       (1596207300,  81), (1596207300,  88), (1596207300,  96),
       (1596207300, 115), (1596207300, 118), (1596207300, 123),
       (1596207300, 125), (1596207300, 127), (1596207300, 128),
       (1596207300, 129), (1596207300, 147), (1596207300, 150),
       (1596207300, 156), (1596207300, 158), (1596207300, 162),
       (1596207300, 164), (1596207300, 165), (1596207300, 170),
       (1596207300, 171), (1596207300, 172), (1596207300, 173),
       (1596207300, 188), (1596207300, 189), (1596207300, 202),
       (1596207300, 241), (1596207300, 255), (1596207300, 257),
       (1596207300, 258), (1596207300, 260), (1596207300, 275),
       (1596207300, 276), (1596207300, 277), (1596207300, 278),
       (1596207300, 279), (1596207300, 280), (1596207300, 283),
       (1596207300, 285), (1596207300, 287), (1596207300, 296),
       (1596207300, 301), (1596207300, 302), (1596207300, 303),
       (1596207300, 313), (1596207300, 315), (1596207300, 316),
       (1596208200, 321), (1596208200, 322), (1596208200, 323),
       (1596208200, 348), (1596208200, 350), (1596208200, 352),
       (1596208200, 360), (1596208200, 370), (1596208200, 371),
       (1596208200, 373), (1596208200, 379), (1596208200, 380),
       (1596212220, 389), (1596212220, 391), (1596212220, 392)],
      dtype={'names':['time','value'], 'formats':['<u4','<u4'], 'offsets':[0,16], 'itemsize':20})
```

`time` column consists of timestamps (by minute). I want to extract rows with the biggest `value` per each time.

By `[ arr[ arr['time'] == uTime ]['value'].max() for uTime in np.unique( arr['time'] ) ]`, I could get the biggest values per each time, which are [316, 380, 392], but I don't know how to simply extract the entire rows that contain the values.

The result I want to get:

```
array([(1596207300, 316), (1596208200, 380), (1596212220, 392)], dtype={'names':['time','value'], 'formats':['<u4','<u4'], 'offsets':[0,16], 'itemsize':20})
```

Comment: You're using NumPy for the wrong thing; I think that Pandas would be better suited to what you want to do. NumPy is optimized for linear algebra, and it looks like you need a library that performs relational algebra.

Comment: @Nolan Faught Thank you for the comment. Using Pandas will be easier. The thing is that there are many arrays to process and I want to use Numba and Numpy together for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got what you want. Just add uTime to the array construction:

```
[ [uTime, arr[ arr['time'] == uTime ]['value'].max()] for uTime in np.unique( arr['time']
```

**Update**
If you want the entire row to be in the result, I would suggest iterating manually. The following code works if `timestamps` come sequentially.

```
cols = {"time":0, "value":1, ...}
time_ = None
res = []
mx_row = arr[0]
for row in arr:

    if time_ == None:
        time_ = row[cols["time"]]

    if time_ != row[cols["time"]]:
        res.append(mx_row)
        time_ = None

    mx_row = max(mx_row, row, key=lambda x: x[cols["value"]])
```

If the data is not sorted, you might want to sort it according to the timestamp.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My bad. There are other columns but I excluded them to simplify the question. Do you happen to know how to mask the original array and get the result?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this:

```
n = np.unique( arr['time'] )
l = [ arr[ arr['time'] == uTime ]['value'].max() for uTime in n ]
arr[(np.in1d(arr['time'], n)) & ((np.in1d(arr['value'], l)))]
```

Prints:

```
array([(1596207300, 316), (1596208200, 380), (1596212220, 392)],
      dtype={'names':['time','value'], 'formats':['<u4','<u4'], 'offsets':[0,16], 'itemsize':20})
```

The first two lines are the same thing that you did. I just used that code to create two 1d lists of unique 'times' and their corresponding max 'values'. Then used [np.1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to mask the original array as you require.